# Google Directory API user creation and then sending a welcome email

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I have created an API request that successfully inserts a user into a Google directory via the Google directory_v1 API.

In the admin console GUI, after one creates a user, one has the option to send the login information via a beautiful email to the users secondary email. My decision for now is to send a welcome email myself via the gmail API after a 200 response as this functionality does not seem to be supported by the any of the admin sdks, is it?

Comment: For that, it may depend on your use-case but you have to use the Gmail API.Then create a trigger for the function for every successful user creation. You can check this official documentation of Google regarding [Sending Email](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending). Hope this helps.